# Styling long chains in Python

Tags: python

I've written a Python API that is "chain based" (similar to jQuery). So I can write:

```py
myObject.doStuff().doMoreStuf().goRed().goBlue().die()
```

The problem is that I haven't found a way to keep the syntax clean with long chains. In JavaScript I could simply do

```py
myOjbect
   .doStuf()
   .doMoreStuf()
   .goRed()
   .goBlue()
   .die()
```

but Python has indentation restrictions...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## PEP8-compliant solution: formatting the line

Actually [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) says:

> Long lines can be
>       broken over multiple lines by wrapping expressions in **parentheses. These
>       should be used in preference to using a backslash for line continuation**.
>       Make sure to indent the continued line appropriately.

So I suppose your code should look like this:

```
(
    myOjbect
    .doStuf()
    .doMoreStuf()
    .goRed()
    .goBlue()
    .die()
)
```

## Alternative solutions: splitting into separate statements

Judging from the syntax, there are two options possible regarding the values returned by each method call:

1. Every method (maybe except `die()`, which is not required, as its result is not being used) returns modified instance (the same instance, on which it was called).
2. Every method (still, `die()` is not required to do that) returns *copy* of the instance on which it was called.

### Solution for mutable objects (methods return original instance)

In **first case** (when returning same instance), the solution to split longer lines into several statements is:

```
myObject.doStuf()
myObject.doMoreStuf()
myObject.goRed()
myObject.goBlue()
myObject.die()
```

Real world example involves mutable objects:

```
my_stuff = []
my_stuff.append('laptop')  # my_stuff == ['laptop']
my_stuff.append('jacket')  # my_stuff == ['laptop', 'jacket']
my_stuff.append('apple')  # my_stuff == ['laptop', 'jacket', 'apple']
```

(although `list.append()` does not return anything, just for consistency and for stating explicitly that it is mutable)

### Solution for immutable objects (methods return modified copy)

In the **second case** (when returning copy), the solution to do similar thing is:

```
myObject = myObject.doStuf()
myObject = myObject.doMoreStuf()
myObject = myObject.goRed()
myObject = myObject.goBlue()
myObject.die()
```

Real world example involves immutable objects:

```
name = '-Tadek-'
name = name.strip('-')  # name == 'Tadek'
name = name.lower()  # name == 'tadek'
name = name.replace('k', 'ck')  # name == 'tadeck'
```

Comment: Can't disagree with a PEP, but I don't like that style much.

Comment: @Joe: Yes, long statements look ugly and un-pythonic, but I really like this more than multiple backslashes (no pun intended) :) But there is something I like even more: the APIs that do not force me to use chained statements.

Comment: It just makes it look like an expression rather than a statement. I know the line between the two is a bit fuzzy, but still, doesn't feel right.

Comment: @Joe: You are right, it looks like expression. But in fact it is / may be an expression. For Python it does not matter much - if you assign it like that: `result = ( ...[multi-line statement]... )`, then `result` will have the value returned by the last element of the chain or `None` (if nothing is returned). So in fact it does not matter much - it can be treated as expression. Although every multi-line statement / expression in Python looks ugly to me. It is probably because I expect more clarity and purity from Python code :)

Comment: @Tadeck: Can you list some specific examples of "the APIs that do not force me to use chained statements"?  I'm curious what the alternatives are.  Thank you.

Comment: @ZacharyYoung: You can store current state within the API object (`myObject` in this case), use [decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) etc. So the example API could use one object like that: `myObject.doStuff(); myObject.doMoreStuff(); myObject.goRed(); myObject.goBlue(); myObject.die()` (just replace "`; `" with line breaks).

Comment: @Tadeck State is being stored within `myObject` (i.e. each method is returning an updated version of `self`), which is why chaining works in the first place. So this version is no different semantically, and simply more verbose (and I would argue less elegant).

Answer (score 7):

```
myOjbect \
   .doStuf() \
   .doMoreStuf() \
   .goRed() \
   .goBlue() \
   .die()
```

(I feel sorry for `myObject`. That all sounds quite painful.)

Answer (score 6):

Though I wouldn't call it "clean", it is possible to break inside the parenthesis:

```
myOjbect.doStuf(
   ).doMoreStuf(arg1, arg2
   ).goRed(
   ).goBlue(
   ).die()
```

Tastes vary though, so I'm putting it in an answer for completeness.

Answer (score 3):

I found that a good way to make “chains” look nice is to simply type a bit more:

```
obj = myObject.doStuff()
obj = obj.doMoreStuf()
obj = obj.goRed()
obj = obj.goBlue()
obj = obj.die()
```

Or better: use meaningful names, making the code more obvious.

```
obj = myObject.doStuff().doMoreStuf()
colored_object = obj.goRed().goBlue()
colored_object.die()
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't think chained methods like this are used very commonly in python (if at all).  One option would be to use an API that looks like

```
myObject.do(
    'Stuff',
    'MoreStuff',
    'Red',
    'Blue',
    'die',
    )
```

though you might get more relevant advice if you give us a real example - it's hard to guess what kind of operations are being represented here.  Maybe some of them should be combined, or placed in `__init__` (for example, the colour could be set by passing an optional argument to `__init__`).

Comment: -1: Dispatching by string like that is not very common either and I think it's bad practice, because it makes the code less analyzable, because you have to rely on documentation to publish the available methods.

Comment: One example of chained invocations is in the Django Queryset api (which is used by lots of folks).